# What mechanism allows AS3 xml data to be referenced in a class yet persist when the original object is destroyed

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a class instance called _refXMLManager that contains some XML data and I can reference the data by _refXMLManager.xmlData.

I have a second class called XMLREFTEST:

```
package {
 public class XMLREFTEST {
 private var _data:XML;

  function XMLREFTEST(data:XML) {
    _data=data
  }

  public function get data():XML {
    return _data;
  }

 }
}
```

I can verify that the data in _xmlRefTest is indeed a reference by changing the value of a node in _refXMLManager and seeing it update in _xmlRefTest.

```
trace("_refXMLManager data: " + _refXMLManager.xmlData.test);
// _refXMLManager data: HELLO WORLD

_xmlRefTest = new XMLREFTEST(_refXMLManager.xmlData);
trace("_xmlRefTest data: " + _xmlRefTest.data.test);
// _xmlRefTest.data: HELLO WORLD

_refXMLManager.xmlData.test="Hi"
trace("_refXMLManager data: " + _refXMLManager.xmlData.test);
// _refXMLManager data: Hi

trace("_xmlRefTest data: " + _xmlRefTest.data.test);
// _xmlRefTest data: Hi
```

I then kill the 'master' object. (The kill function sets the original URLLoader and xmlData in _refXMLManager to null).

```
_refXMLManager.kill();
trace("_refXMLManager.xmlData==null: " + (_refXMLManager.xmlData==null));    
// _refXMLManager.xmlData==null: true

trace("_xmlRefTest data: " + _xmlRefTest.data.test);
// _xmlreftest data: Hi
```

So my question is: what is happening in ActionScript that allows the original XML object to be disposed of and yet allows a reference to it to persist? I wondered if the reference just had to wait to be garbage-collected but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand references and variables in AS3. You cannot kill an object if you still have a least one reference to it.

So _xmlRefTest.data still has a reference to the xml because it did prevent the object from being destroyed in the first place.

You did assume a few things that actually never happened:

- The original object was never destroyed.
- You never actually killed the original xml.
- The xml cannot be GC because it never qualified for it in the first place since there's still at least one reference to it.

Comment: BotMaster thank you for your answer which I have only just become aware of. Your explanation makes perfect sense. It's interesting that a variable can test null even though the value it referenced still exists. I would have expected a nulled variable to pass along that state to all the variables that reference it since after all they are references.